# Combining two sets and splitting them in pairs

Tags: python, tuples, set

I need to take two sets of data and produce one set of pairs(tuples) from both sets. This result set will only have one possible pair, i.e. for two sets: 1,2 and 3, 4 the result should be: ((1, 3), (2, 4)). Full exercise text can be found here:http://pastebin.com/mUaKV4G7

I need to do this using pop. Here's what I have so far:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    pairs = set()
    tmp_males, tmp_females = males.copy(), females.copy()
    for male in tmp_males:
        for female in tmp_females:
            pairs.add(males.pop())
            pairs.add(females.pop())
        zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2])
        return pairs
```

This function works fine up to the point when it reaches:

```
        zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2])
```

without it given two sets it'll combine them together but when I try to use zip to split them in pairs I get this error:

```
'set' object is not subscriptable
```

Which leads me to believe that it's somewhere returning None instead of correct result.

This function need to work with both integers and strings( I don't think it needs to pairing values in a specific order), also both sets will have equal number of values.

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to produce all possible pairs combining every element from 1st set with every element from the 2nd?

Comment: @KL-7 No, just pair one value from 1st with one value from 2nd using pop

Comment: @Andrew Marsh, it's not homework, it's from exercise in a book I'm learning with.

Comment: Could you please fix the identation in the code you posted? It’s not obvious at what identation level the last two lines are supposed to be.

Comment: I assume you're using `pop` because the problem tells you to? If so, keep in mind that it's just an exercise to help you think about data structure manipulation - you would never _actually_ use `pop` to do this in real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you what is going on: `pairs` is a `set` and the expression `pairs[::2]` means "every 2nd element of the set". The problem is that `set`s have no defined order, so "every 2nd element of the set" makes no sense. As the order of element is undefined, Python raises a exception instead of making up a random order.

What you probably wanted to do is either to pair up males and females in the order they appear:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    return zip(males, females)
```

or all possible pairs of males and females (the product of both lists):

```
from itertools import product
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    return product(males, females)
```

Your homework seem to be to implement either `zip` or `product` :-)

Comment: Exercise I have doesn't mention either of these two, your reply answers my question, thank you. Full exercise text can be found here: http://pastebin.com/mUaKV4G7

Comment: @gameFace: This exercise is actually quite pointless.  Why on earth should you empty the input sets while generating the output set?

Answer (score 1):

If you must use pop, try popping both `males` and `females` at once, into a tuple that you add to `pairs` (and, by the way, I'm not sure why you make copies of your sets and destroy the originals, but I suppose you have your reasons).  Also, iterating both `males` and `females` will fail to give you the answer you're looking for - rather, check the emptiness of each set as you pop from it.  What you're looking for is more like this:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    pairs = set()
    tmp_males, tmp_females = males.copy(), females.copy()
    while tmp_males and tmp_females:
        pairs.add((tmp_males.pop(),tmp_females.pop()))
    return pairs
```

though this would be a touch simpler if you can avoid using `set.pop`:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    return set(zip(males,females))
```

Also, please note that this can't be a complete answer unless you are using some sort of ordered set datatype.  As it is using a `set`, **you're not guaranteed to preserve any order** of the `males` and `females` that were passed in.

Comment: I copied the sets in order to be able to iterate over them and at the same time change the originals. Your answer is very elegant and I would have selected it but previous poster answered my question regarding zip.

Answer (score 0):

If using `pop` is forced restriction I'd go with something like that:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    res = set()
    males_copy, females_copy = males.copy(), females.copy()

    while males_copy and females_copy:
        res.add((males_copy.pop(), females_copy.pop()))

    return res

print mating_pairs(set([1, 2, 3]), set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
# => set([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')])
```

But `set(zip(males, females))` is much more easier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I’m a bit unsure what you are trying to do. But analyzing your posted code, I guess you want to combine every male with every female once, and put tuples of each combination into a final list.

If that is the case, then what you are trying to do is creating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). The Python library has a nice function for this: [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can use it like this:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    return set(itertools.product(males, females))
```

If you want to do it the manual way, then you can use two nested for loops to get all combinations. However the way you did it, by utilizing `pop` won’t work. What you did in your code is that you iterated over all males and females (after copying the parameters) and then you pop the items from the original sets. That way, very quickly both sets `males` and `females` will be empty, as you keep popping from them for every possible combination, without considering that you only get all combinations if you keep reusing individual items.

You could fix your code like this, without using pop:

```
def mating_pairs(males, females):
    pairs = set()

    # We only iterate over the items, so we don’t modify the original sets.
    for male in males:
        for female in females:
            # And instead of adding individual items by once, and zipping them
            # later, we just directly add tuples to the set.
            pairs.add((male, female))

    return pairs
```

Comment: I had to combine only one female with one male, so for 2 sets: 1,2 and 3,4 the result would be ((1, 3), (2, 4))